# Will destroying the default Interbus Customs Office in low-sec, reduce standing with Interbus?

Tags: eve-online

Recently Eve added Player owned Customs Offices (POCOs) outside of high-sec.

By default, Interbus owns the Customs Offices outside of High-sec until a player comes along and destroys it, and then replaces it.

Reading the instructions for the new POCOs, I wasn't sure if there would be any faction standing penalty for destroying the default Interbus Customs Offices.

Is there any standing hit for destroying an Interbus Customs Office outside of High-sec?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [devblog announcing the Player owned customs offices](http://www.eveonline.com/devblog.asp?a=blog&nbid=3075):

> The new deployment plan:
>
> - The highsec Customs Offices are transferred to CONCORD as previously planned
> - Ownership of all lowsec, 0.0 and wormhole  Customs Offices is
>     transferred to NPC corp “Interbus”
> - The Interbus Customs Offices can be used for PI or **shot down (without standing or security penalty)**
> - Interbus Customs Offices will not be de-spawned, they  will remain until destroyed by players
> - The Interbus Corporation will charge slightly more tax than CONCORD and we will continue to monitor the tax rates for both CONCORD and
>     Interbus

So there seems to be no standing penalty for shooting down an Interbus-owned Customs Office.

Comment: The penalty for destroying an Interbus POCO is that you have to spend six hours in a battleship configured purely for DPS, sitting still, in lowsec, at a point that doesn't have to be scanned down. Hours of boredom, seconds of terror, frozen corpse in orbit forever :)